# Time reversal in electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

In classical electrodynamics, we know that under time reversal the electric and magnetic potentials should transform as

$$\phi'(x,t)=\phi(x,-t) \qquad A'(x,t)=-A(x,-t) $$

Now, using $(+,-,-,-)$ signature the time reversal operator in special relativity is the (1,1) tensor 
$$T^\mu_{\,\,\nu}=\textrm{diag}(-1,1,1,1) $$

And we know that $A^\mu=(\phi, A)$ transforms as a 4-vector and $A_\mu=(\phi, -A)$, so we should have

$$ A_\nu'=T^\mu_{\,\,\nu}A_\mu=(-\phi, -A)$$

and thus $A'^\nu=(-\phi, A)$, which is wrong.

Why is this the case? It seems like $A^\nu$ should transform under time reversal how I would expect it to transform under parity.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161309/time-reversal-in-classical-electrodynamics

Comment: @caverac I found that answer, unfortunately I only know basic differential geometry and I was hoping for an explanation less heavy on that, not involving the Hodge dual

Comment: @caverac Alternatively, could you suggest a source where I can read about why the 4-current (and the 4-potential) are not 1-forms but the object described in that answer?

Comment: You could read [this](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/3280/1/arntzenius_greaves_TRCE.pdf) or [this](http://jamesowenweatherall.com/SCPPRG/MalamentDavidB2004StudHistPhilModPhys_TimeReversalInv.pdf)